# На форме ничего не отображается

Tags: база-данных, access

**Используется**
Access 2016

**Структура**
Сделал форму со следующей структурой:
Форма 1
Вкладка 1
Форма 2. Таблица 1.
Форма 2. Таблица 1. Поле 1
Вкладка 2
Вкладка 3

Таблица 1 - веншняя

Из **"конструктора"** перехожу в режим **"формы"** получаю пустую форму.
Пустая форма стала, когда начал добавлять поля: "Форма 2. Таблица 1. Поле 1" и т.д.

**Вопрос.**
В чём может быть проблема?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А какой режим у формы стоит по  умолчанию в настройках?

Comment: И пожалуйста добавь полный скрин экран в режиме конструктора

Comment: @blakcat  Свойства http://prntscr.com/eklltj

Comment: Да так ничего не понятно, если можешь сам файл куда нибудь выложить.

Comment: @blakcat Там таблицы внешние используются. Начал готовить файл для отправки. Преобразовал таблицы в локальные проблема пропала. Может  проблема в том, что они внешние?

Comment: @blakcat Точно... Преобразовал таблицу в "локальную". Всё появилось  http://prntscr.com/eklqa2

Comment: А как привязка данных осуществляется? И одну таблицу получается вывести на форму?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55467/discussion-between-blakcat-and-koverflow).